# How to change Ip for a DNS

Tags: docker, dns

I'll be very direct. I'm tired to search this and do not found anything about it.
There is any way to change a lan ip to a dns (not chaging 'hosts' file)?
Example:
I've a centOs running in machine A and code any types of code in machine B.
Either machine A and B are in same local area network and have differetns IP's.
So, Machine B has 10.0.0.2 as IP and Machine B has 10.0.0.3.
Machine A has docker on it, and I can acess from machine B as 10.0.0.2:xxxx
What I'm trying to accomplish is:
Machine B insted of reaching machine A with IP (10.0.0.2:xxxx) I'm intend to reach with anyname.dsv.local.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. You have to set up [BIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND) as a Private Network DNS Server.